# Mediawiki cannot find 'three' in search

Tags: unicode, mediawiki, hebrew

I have two installations of mediawiki on two different hosting services. When I search for 'three' it can find it in pagenames to display on the search dropdown while I am typing, but cannot find it in the pagename or body for the actual search.

If I search for 'three a' it lists pages with 'a', and then bolds 'three' on the listing.

https://2ndbook.org/w/index.php?search=Three&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=all&fulltext=1

https://sensusplenior.net/wiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=Search&search=Three&ns0=1&ns6=1&ns8=1&ns10=1&ns14=1&profile=advanced

I use a Hebrew font and switch to it while typing using Win+space.

I don't have command line access to either installation.

I have tried deleting pages and recreating them. Adding 'three' to random pages.

Perhaps there is a unicode character in the body if a page which kills the search?

Added:
I have a Terminology page that stressed the limits of transclusions.  Each single and double letter Hebrew entry had four or more transclusions.  I have since emptied that page, and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Your question is not about programming, so it is off-topic. Note: the process which prepare indices on your wiki may run later (many hours later), or just you didn;t configured it.

Comment: Thanks. Search works for everything else.   Though many may disagree.  Mediawiki scripting is a programming language of sorts.  There is a bug,  either in the mediawiki engine, the transclusion scripts, or the use of unicode in the data.  Perhaps the transclusion limits (maybe analogous to a looping limit in code) is the issue and the next time the indexing runs it will be fixed.   However, when I add an article, it is immediately available in search, so I doubt that the 'indexing' is delayed as much as you believe.

Answer (score 0):

'Three' is on the list of stop words.   The fix is here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

And it is a reminder that black swan events are built into the invisible assumptions that come along with all the tech we adopt without fully understanding.